# Visual studio when i try to add reference get this : Instance object set as constant

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reflection

I dont know what does it say or how to fix it anyone has idea ?
I also have tried to add this plugin interface to another project but got same error.
So I think the problem is about this plugin setup.
Here is my interface below

```
using DEMIRBANKLIB;
namespace DPlugin
{
    public interface DPlugin
    {
        public enum EVENTTYPE {GETPACKAGE,SENDPACKAGE,LOADTABLE }
        public string Name { get; set; }   
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public EventManager manager { get; set; }
        public void Run();
    }
    public class EventManager
    {
        IPaket paket;
        Dictionary<DPlugin.EVENTTYPE,EventDelegate> events = new Dictionary<DPlugin.EVENTTYPE,EventDelegate>();
        public delegate void EventDelegate(IPaket paket);

        public bool RegisterEvent(DPlugin.EVENTTYPE TYPE,EventDelegate del)
        {
            if (events[TYPE] == null)
                events.Add(TYPE, del);
            else
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the plugin i want to use.

```
using DPlugin;
using DEMIRBANKLIB;
namespace PaketEventP
{
    public class PEP : DPlugin.DPlugin
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }    
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public EventManager manager { get; set; }
        public PEP()
        {
            Name = "Paket Eventi Plugin";
            Description = "Paket eventleri ile bir şeyler yapcak";
            manager = new EventManager();
            
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            manager.RegisterEvent(DPlugin.DPlugin.EVENTTYPE.GETPACKAGE, paketAlEvent); 
        }
        public void paketAlEvent(IPaket paket)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(paket.detay);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly did you do? Where does this message appear? What is the relation to Reflection?

Comment: i try to add a dll referance(plugin) which includes refleciton codes but the suprising thing i cant add any kind of libraries anymore in this solution. I have even tried to add irrevelant plugin interface(library) to add my plugin but got same error.

Comment: Okay the problem is about this plugin or maybe the project so i share my codes

Comment: Hi ali demir, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered.
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Use reflection to generate objects and call properties, methods and fields to operate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by editing solution codes manually.